# QTableWidget and generate English number as number row

Tags: python, qt, localization, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have the following `QTableWidget`:
[image: my program]

My program is Perisan language in `(Persian,Iran) locale`,But `Qt` itself generate a set of number for each row in English language.

My question is, How i change the above numbers to my locale?(۰,۱,۲,۳,۴,۵,۶,۷,۸,۹)

Comment: Maybe you should set correct font?

Comment: i didn't manipulate fonts, also i have many Persian fonts on my machine.

Comment: Could you provide code, where you return data to "number" row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `QTableWidget` you can set header text yourself with `QTableWidget::setVerticalHeaderLabels`.

If you switch to model/view approach you can reimplement `QAbstractItemModel::headerData`:

```
QVariant MyModel::headerData (int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Vertical && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        QString persianDigit = ...;// get number in Persian from section value
        return persianDigit;
    }
    else
    {
         return QAbstractItemModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
    }
}
```